# Regex to validate the numbers between 0 to 65535

Tags: regex

I need a regex to validate the positive numbers in the range 0 to 65535.

Allowed : 0,1,2....10,...65535

Not Allowed : 001, 000032, 1.00, 100.11, 01.10 etc.

Comment: ^[0-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]?$|^65535$.....Will this workout?

Comment: No then I can't enter 100, 1000 etc.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

this one works for all 0 to 65535.

Comment: I think `[0-5][0-9]{4}` should be `[1-5][0-9]{4}`, otherwise you'd allow leading zeroes, including `00000` which seems incorrect.

Comment: ^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]{1}|6553[0-5])$ | ^0$......this one looks fine but I need to escape the ' , ' in {0,3}

Comment: @Renju, may i know why ?

Comment: [0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?

Comment: ^([1-9][0-9]{0\,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]{1}|6553[0-5])$|^0$..........This one works perfectly fine....escape for ' , ' also captured

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
^(0|6[0-5][0-5][0-3][0-5]|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$
```

Go ahead and try it out at
https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit inelegant, but I believe this works:

```
0|([1-5][0-9]{0,4})|(6[1-4,0][0-9]{0,3})|(65[1-4,0][0-9]{0,2})|(655[1-2,0][0-9])|(6553[1-5,0])
```

https://regex101.com/r/XkpDHb/4

Not sure of a better way to get regex to understand numbers as values and not a list of digits.

Comment: but this will take 01, 001, 0001 etc., if I'm right

Comment: No it won't, since if the first digit matches 0 then that has to be the entire string (since the rest are 'or's). Each other or branch requires that the first digit be some value greater than 0. This will not match `000` however, in case that was also possible.

Comment: You are missing values which start with `[789]`

Comment: `[1-4,0]` means `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `,` or `0`. There's nothing in the question about allowing `,`.